# SaveChanges() Does not work

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a very simple table 
1: Code - int
2: Name string

and using EntityFramework

```
       Dim dbContext As New MyEntities
       Dim myCategory As New Category
       myCategory .code = txtCategoryCode.Text
       myCategory .Name = txtCategoryName.Text

        dbContext.AddToCategory(myCategory )
        dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

No error but it does nots ave the data in DB !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
dbContext.AddToCategory(myCategory)
```

try

```
dbContext.Category.Add(myCategory)
```

or if it does not work, then try

```
dbContext.Categories.Add(myCategory)
```